# LXml Xpath processing of multi-line field

Tags: xpath, screen-scraping, lxml

I'm doing some scraping of a page and I'm fine with getting most fields, but having some problems with the address.

```
<address>
  56 South Ave
  <br>
  Miami, FL 33131
  <br>
</address>
```

address  = myWebPage.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'rightcol')]//address")

I can get the first line, 56 South Avenue, using the above code.  But I can't get the city, state, zip.  How would I change the code to get the full address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//div[contains(@class,'rightcol')]//address/text()[1]
```

selects the first text-node child of `address`:

```
"  
  56 South Ave   
  "

//div[contains(@class,'rightcol')]//address/text()[2]
```

selects the second text-node child of `address`:

```
"       
  Miami, FL 33131       
  "

//div[contains(@class,'rightcol')]//address/text()
```

selects both text-node children of `address`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dmitre.  It works.

Another question for you:
Although I get ok results when I select for either node1 or node2, I realize that my results are terminated early if I do //address/text().  I only 3 results whereas there are 10 children of address.

This may be due to extra non-alphanumeric characters in the address.  I'm not sure.  I'd normally do some regex parsing but not sure if i can do that within the xpath functions. How do you typically process multiline data to ensure results are well-formed?

Comment: @DevX: `//address/text()` selects all text nodes that are *immediate* children of an `address` element. In case you need all text-node *descendents` of any `address` node, use: `//address//text()`.